# Why is an array that is passed correctly via props returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I'm trying to load each string of an array of strings in a `<li>` html tag by passing this array via props:

```
<CardItem
  src='https://static.news...koinex-banner.png'
  text='my text'
  label='Adventure'
  path='/products'
  description={["someText1", "someText2", "someText3", "someText4"]}
/>
```

```
function CardItem(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <li className='cards__item'>
        <Link className='cards__item__link' to={props.path}>
          <figure className='cards__item__pic-wrap' data-category={props.label}>
            <img
              className='cards__item__img'
              alt='Travel Image'
              src={props.src}
            />
          </figure>
          <div className='cards__item__info'>
            <h5 className='cards__item__text'>{props.text}</h5>
          </div>
          <CardDescription description={props.description} />
        </Link>
      </li>
    </>
  );
}

export default CardItem;
```

```
function CardDescription(props) {
  return (
      <div>
          <ul>
              <li>{props.description[0]} </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  )
}

export default CardDescription
```

And I'm getting

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

I'm not sure why `props.description` prop is returning undefined.

Also, this TypeError seems to only be happening with the `props.description` prop.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Also, you might want to fix the spelling. `CardDescrition`

Comment: where do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is misspelled `CardDescrition`  to `CardDescription`

Try:

```
{props.description ? <CardDescription description={props.description} /> : ''}
```

and in description:

```
function CardDescription(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {props.description.map(des => <li>des</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

please find the minimal repo I created:

https://github.com/snake-py/so-help-react-card

Explanation:

I try to explain from what I understand what is happening there.

When Carditems mounts it seems even though you hard code the values, that they are not passed on the initial render. Hence, the ternary check if the props include the `description` array.

I am guessing now why that is:

Perhaps because they are inside a wrapper component of `Link`. If you remove the `Link` component the code should work without the initial check.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: I made a minimal repo, I notice you have also a typo in your code. https://github.com/snake-py/so-help-react-card

Comment: oh, I just noticed, that I had not pushed the code. Sorry, Now everything should be there.

Comment: omg it actually works!! Thank you so much!! Would you care to elaborate what the problem was, exactly?

Comment: I added an explanation, not sure if it is correct. Perhaps someone with more experience can swing by and confirm my guess.

Comment: thank you so much, I really aprecciate your help

Answer (score 1):

well, that's probably because during the mounting of the three the description prop could be undefined, you could avoid this error by doing this `props?.description[0]`, also if you want to render all the values in the array inside the CardDescrition component you could do this

```
   props?.description.map((item) => (<li>{item}</li>))
```

Comment: Hey jhonny, thanks for the reply! This show some other error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: Just add a ? after description, so `props?.description?.map((item) => (<li>{item}</li>))`

Comment: I think this would be the problem if the value would be computed. But it is hardcoded.